# I'm trying to call a function.  What is the cause of these silly compilation errors?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-calls

I'm trying to run this c++ program I wrote. I'm getting the following errors in Visual C++:

> 1>c:\users\server\desktop\problem7\problem7\main.cpp(26) : error C3867: 'Payment::getamount': function call missing argument list; use '&Payment::getamount' to create a pointer to member
>
> 1>c:\users\server\desktop\problem7\problem7\main.cpp(74) : error C3867: 'cashPayment::paymentDetails': function call missing argument list; use '&cashPayment::paymentDetails' to create a pointer to member
>
> 1>c:\users\server\desktop\problem7\problem7\main.cpp(75) : error C3867: 'CreditCardPayment::paymentDetails': function call missing argument list; use '&CreditCardPayment::paymentDetails' to create a pointer to member

the code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Payment
{
private: float amount;

public: Payment(float=0.0);
        void paymentDetails();
        float getamount();
        void setamount(float);
};


Payment::Payment(float a)
{
    setamount(a);
}

void Payment::setamount(float a){amount=a;}
float Payment::getamount(){return amount;}

void Payment::paymentDetails()
{
    cout<<"The amount of payment is : "<<getamount<<"$"<<endl;
}

class cashPayment: public Payment
{
public: cashPayment(float=0.0);
        void paymentDetails();
};
cashPayment::cashPayment(float a):Payment(a){};
void cashPayment::paymentDetails()
{
    cout<<"The payment in cash is : "<<getamount()<<"$"<<endl;
}

class CreditCardPayment: public Payment
{
private: char* name;
         int creditnumber;
         int day,month,year;

public: CreditCardPayment(char[]=" ",int=0, int=0, int=0, int=0 ,float=0.0);
        void paymentDetails();
};

CreditCardPayment::CreditCardPayment(char* n, int cn, int d, int m, int y, float a):Payment(a)
{
    int l=strlen(n);
    name = new char[l+1];
    strncpy(name,n,l);
    name[l]='\0';
    creditnumber=cn;
    day=d;
    month=m;
    year=y;
}
void CreditCardPayment::paymentDetails()
{
    cout<<"Credit Card Holder Information & Payment: "<<endl;
    cout<<"Name is "<<name<<endl;
    cout<<"Credit Number is "<<creditnumber<<endl;
    cout<<"Expiration Date (Day / Month / Year) is "<<day<<"/"<<month<<"/"<<year<<endl;
    //cout<<"Payment is "<<Payment::getamount()<<"$"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    CreditCardPayment cc1("Mohammad",936623,21,9,2011,3000);
    cashPayment cp1(4500);
    cp1.paymentDetails;
    cc1.paymentDetails;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to buy some parentheses? `cp1.paymentDetails` => `cp1.paymentDetails()`.

Comment: First, you should indicate which lines in the code (with comments) are the ones generating the errors, so that people can find them easily.

Comment: @KenWhite: To be fair the compile errors have line numbers and there are only a few lines where the errors make sense.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, true. But the poster has the exact line positions that the compiler is flagging (and can find and mark them in the code editor before posting here), and marking them makes what needs to be scanned to find the cause clearer. The less code you have to read to start with, the quicker you can spot the problem and provide an answer, and the quicker the asker gets back to work. :) And I didn't downvote the question - I made a suggestion to the person asking the question to help people trying to help him/her.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In here:

```
void Payment::paymentDetails()
{
    cout<<"The amount of payment is : "<<getamount<<"$"<<endl;
}
```

the compiler is telling you that you might have meant `getamount()` instead of `getamount`.

Similarly here:

```
cp1.paymentDetails;
cc1.paymentDetails;
```

you probably meant:

```
cp1.paymentDetails();
cc1.paymentDetails();
```

Unlike some other languages, in C++ when you call a function that takes no arguments you must still provide an empty argument list in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

```
cp1.paymentDetails;
cc1.paymentDetails;
```

The error states "function call missing argument list."  Your function calls are indeed missing the argument lists.  You need to use `()` to call the functions:

```
cp1.paymentDetails();
cc1.paymentDetails();
```

The second half of the error, which reads "'&Payment::getamount' to create a pointer to member" is a "helpful" hint that if you meant to take the address of the function, you need to use the unary `&` (address-of) operator.

This hint is there because the operator is *not* required for computing the address of a non-member function (for compatibility with C and for legacy code), but it is required for computing the address of a nonstatic member function.